# Why does function composition require parentheses?

Tags: haskell, syntax, operator-precedence, function-composition

Let's say I want to compose `Text.pack` with `Text.strip`.

`:t (.)` produces: `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`

`:t (Text.pack)` produces: `String -> Text`

`:t (Text.strip)` produces: `Text -> Text`

So substituting `strip` for `(b -> c)` gives:
`b = Text`
`c = Text`

Substituting `pack` for `(a -> b)` gives:
`a = String`
`b = Text`

Lets verify: `:t strip . pack` produces:
`strip . pack :: String -> Text`

ok, great lets try it:

`strip.pack "    example     "`

Produces:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘a -> Text’ with actual type ‘Text’
Relevant bindings include
  it :: a -> Text (bound at <interactive>:31:1)
Possible cause: ‘pack’ is applied to too many arguments
In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘pack "    example     "’
In the expression: strip . pack "    example     "
```

`(strip . pack) "     example     "` works as expected.... why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Function application has a higher priority than composition.

`strip.pack "    example     "` is equivalent to `strip.(pack "    example    ")`. This is one reason why people use `$` to "suppress" application until after all the functions have been composed:

```
strip . pack $ "    example     "
```

Comment: Even stronger, function application has a higher priority than *anything else*.

Comment: This precedence allows e.g. `filter even . map (+5)`. Composing partially applied functions is rather idiomatic. Also note that the order of arguments for `map,filter,...` was picked so to make this convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Function application has an higher precedence over the function composition operator.